# ASP.NET - How to use Response.Redirect() from within User Control? (.ascx)

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm converting some ASPX pages to user controls (ASCX).

I still need some of the page redirection to work.. and server.transfer is not an option (I need the URL in the address bar to change).

Is there a way to either user Response.Redirect() from within a user control or a similar method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Page.Response.Redirect() inside UserControls.